# how to create a unique CONCAT field in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL statement that does not work like planned:

```
SELECT sr.item as Business_Component, sr.user_email as Email, UNIQUE CONCAT(sr.user_email+bc.bus_comp+e.taxyear), e.w2_wages as wages, sr.taxyear as taxyear FROM survey_results sr, business_components bc, employees e WHERE sr.item_type='BC' AND sr.user_email=e.employee_email AND sr.item=bc.bus_comp AND GROUP BY sr.item, sr.user_email
```

I am trying to make sure that the combo of the e.employee_email+bc.bus_comp+e.taxyear is unique among all the results. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: UNIQUE is a constraint keyword used when creating a table.  DISTINCT will return unique rows.  SELECT DISTINCT col1, col2, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to make sure that the combo of the e.employee_email+bc.bus_comp+e.taxyear is unique among all the results. What am I doing wrong?

If you want something to be distinct, then `group by` is one method.  `Unique` is not used in this way at all.

Although the following does not seem to do anything useful, it answers your question:

```
SELECT CONCAT(sr.user_email, bc.bus_comp, e.taxyear) as whatever,
       MAX(sr.item) as Business_Component,
       MAX(sr.user_email) as Email, 
       MAX(e.w2_wages) as wages,
       MAX(sr.taxyear) as taxyear
FROM survey_results sr JOIN
     business_components bc
     ON sr.item = bc.bus_comp JOIN
     employees e
     ON sr.user_email = e.employee_email
WHERE sr.item_type  ='BC' 
GROUP BY whatever;
```